# How to create index on a child node nested child key?

Tags: android, performance, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say my current structure firebase realtime database:

```
{ 
chatRooms:{
  chat1:{
   participants:{
    user1-id:true,
    user2-id:true
   }
   participantsCount:2,
   lastTimeUpdated: {TIMESTAMP},
   chatRoomName:"A chatroom",
   maxParticipantsCount:10
   }
  }
users:{
  user1-id:{
   name:user1-name,
   email:user1-email
  }
  user2-id:{
   name:user2-name,
   email:user2-email
   }
 }
}
```

I need to display all chatrooms that contains a specific user along with all its information, and my solution now is:

```
#userId is currently authenticated, firebase user.
ref.child("chats").orderByChild("/participants/"+userId).equalTo(true)
```

which returns the list of chats containing $userId which equals to true, along with additional information to display to the user. Is there any possible way to change this query AND/OR database structure to support optimal indexing? If I wanted to add indices, it would be something like:

```
chatrooms:{
 participants:{
  indexOn:"user1-id","user2-id" 
# number of ids grows as participants increase
# Not only that, I will have to add one by one manually.
 }
}
```

How can I add indices and also at the same time do a query in Android that will display all chatrooms that a user belongs to along with their information?

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK, I cannot "loop" over the keys of the child in Android

To loop over the children of a snapshot in Android do:

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
  System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
}
```

Relevant section in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

---

If you're asking how to display the information about each chat room that a user is in, that will take a client-side join like this:

```
firebase.database().ref("userChatrooms").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).once(function(roomsSnapshot) {
  roomsSnapshot.forEach(function(roomKey) {
    firebase.database().ref("chatrooms").child(roomKey.key).once(function(roomSnapshot) {
      console.log(roomSnapshot.child("name").val());
    })
  })
})
```

This type of client-side join is not nearly as slow as most developers expect, since [Firebase pipelines the nested requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
I think I might have chosen the wrong example with chatrooms, and used incorrect wording.
let's say that I need to get some information of all chatrooms displayed to the user, such as the number of members in the chatroom, and also other information that is available in the "chatrooms" node.
And I need this information displayed to the user.
I eventually cannot just "loop" over them as in query, not looping in the Android itself, right?
I will edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: I honestly am lost on what your question is. Typically adding more information doesn't help in that case. It's better to reduce the question to its minimum. All I can see right now is that your `ref.child("chats").orderByChild("/participants/"+userId).equalTo(true)` is still trying to determine the chat rooms for a user with a query, which won't work as I explained in the question you linked.

Comment: I added an additional explanation in hopes that is what you're looking for. If not: I recommend restating your question.

Comment: I will try to restate my question later. this my first ever question on SO, thanks for your feedback.